# Git push says everything is up to date but remote changes does not reflect! why?

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface

**git push**

*Everything up to date!*

When I am pushing file to Git hub It show that Everything is up to date but in my remote repository I don't see any changes. Please help me why it's happening? Also please clarify the reason behind it.

One more thing I want add here is this problem started when I use command

**git pull**

But after that if I am trying to commit changes file in my local repository it doesn't take effect.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I salute your willingness to write self-answered questions, this is good practice and welcomed here. However, I'm afraid this is all too vague and fragile to be useful. Maybe take some time to work on it a bit more, then center around a more specific problem?

Answer (score -2):

First check your changes are getting commited if not then you may be using

**git commit -m "changes Commited"**

To fix error add a flag in above command.
New command will be...

**git commit -a -m "changes commited"**

Now your commit will execute and reflected.
then use

**git push**

I hope it will help. Thank You!